# New lines in Emmett

Tags: html, newline, emmet

I am brand new to Emmet (18 hours) it is GREAT. I have looked widely but cannot find a way of adding new lines when not added automatically.

```
.container>.row>.col-sm-3>ul>li#abc$*5
```

gives

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <ul>
                <li id="abc1"></li>
                <li id="abc2"></li>
                <li id="abc3"></li>
                <li id="abc4"></li>
                <li id="abc5"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

super easy to work on in PhpStorm or Sublime etc. But

```
.containter>.row>.col-sm-offset-4>form>(input:text)*5+input:email+input:tel
```

give a very messy

```
<div class="containter">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-4">
            <form action=""><input type="text" name="" id=""><input type="text" name="" id=""><input type="text"
                                                                                                          name=""
                                                                                                          id=""><input
                    type="text" name="" id=""><input type="text" name="" id=""><input type="email" name=""
                                                                                          id=""><input type="tel"
                                                                                                        name="" id="">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

OK it is fairly straighforward to sort out by selecting the `><` but silly.

I tried inserting `/n` in various places but to no obvious effect.

So is there a way of forcing a new line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, only the accepted solution didn't help me for PhpStorm.

In PhpStorm you have to remove the HTML tag you want on a new line from a specific list in your PhpStorm settings. You can find it at **Preferences>Editor>Code Style>HTML>Other>Inline elements:** Remove input or any other element you don't want inline and voila! Next time you use emmet your code will look nice and clean.

Comment: For PhpStorm specifically this works fine!!! But PS still mucks up `input:text` producing `<input:text></input:text>`. The whole Emmet implementation seems pretty buggered in fact but at least the new line problem is solved for this :-) Thanks and sorry for the late recognition.

Comment: Thanks. No problem. I agree, at least at the time I used Emmet in PhpStorm. You can use `inp` instead of `input:text`. Works in the latest version of PyCharm, should also work in PhpStorm. Produces the same result and is a lot shorter.

Answer (score 8):

Like the previous answer, the accepted solution didn't work for me, so

in my case, I added a pair of parentheses between the sibling HTML elements:

```
p{Content 1}+{}+p{Content 2}
```

which turned into:

```
<p>Content 1</p>
<p>Content 2</p>
```

I hope someone finds it useful!

Answer (score 4):

I recently had a similar issue, and want all my completions to make line-breaks.  Working in VS Code (dunno if other editors have comparable settings) I went to my `settings.json` file and inside `"emmet.preferences"` put `"output.inlineBreak": 1`.  This basically says "If you have one object in a nested region, give it a line break."  If you set it to two, then it'll only linebreak when two objects are in a nested region.  The default is 3.

Comment: This solution worked for me using Visual Studio Code as well. Recommended!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you’re using PhpStorm which has it’s own Emmet implementation.
Official Emmet (in Sublime Text, for example) produces nice HTML code.

Anyways, your points of interests are:

1. `inline_break` option from [syntax profile](http://docs.emmet.io/customization/syntax-profiles/) settings.
2. Try to use `${newline}` variable in text node, e.g. `input:email+{${newline}}+input:tel`

Don’t know if it works in PhpStorm

Comment: Sergey thanks a million. Yep using Storm. Will try later on.

Comment: When I tried to expand ``.classname{${newline}...${newline}}*3`` I got really poor indentation on the closing of the div in Sublime Text 3. Any ideas?