# I can't get <a></a> tags in new lines when using emmet in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

[image]

When I enter a*5, I expected to get five  tags in new lines. However, the five tags I got were in the same line like this.

[image]

How should I change my settings in VScode in order to have five tags in new lines?

[image]

Comment: For your reference, I [created a new issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116634) on VS Code's repo about inline tags not starting at new lines and they responded that it is designed that way. I remember inline tags used to always start at new lines so maybe they changed something

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It look like you need this in your settings:

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {

  "html": {
    "inline_break": 1
  },
},
```

That will put all tags, including `span` and other typically inline tags, on their own line.  There is no way to restrict it to `a` tags.

I thought `"tag_nl" : true` would work but it didn't.

See [emmet syntaxProfiles](https://docs.emmet.io/customization/syntax-profiles/).

Comment: Thanks buddy, I can get inline tags in new lines using emmet.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution here didn't work for me, but I could solve with the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73006632/19613968) by Addem.
It basically says, in the settings.json file (Ctrl + , > Extensions > Emmet > Preferences > Edit in "settings.json"), add this line:

```
    "emmet.preferences": {
    "output.inlineBreak": 1,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to File> Preferences > Settings
or you can use shortcut (Ctrl +,)
You'll see Extensions> Emmet > scroll down and you'll find Preferences. Click Edit in settings.json
Use the code from below:

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {

  "html": {
    "inline_break": 1
  },
}
```