# HTML emmet tag configuration

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

I am a beginner on the HTML format document.I just tried to use emmet like that in VSCode
".cal-row*4>button.calc-button*4 "
The result was like the image below.[image]

However, I want to make the tags like the image below by using Emmet shortcuts.
It's pain in the ass to struggle with the tags and configuration for the buttons.
How can I change the settings in order to make my emmet configuration like that, when I entered a  shortcut similar to my example.
I could not find how to fix it, if you know some plugins or setting to fix that, I am open to taking advice.
[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66293167/i-cant-get-a-a-tags-in-new-lines-when-using-emmet-in-vs-code/66296921#66296921 probably the same fix.

Answer (score -1):

You should use a prettier - code formatter. It is the easiest way to format your code.
You will have to install it first and you can install it directly from the vs code.
Go to the Extensions tab and search for it and install it.

You can also configure it according to your need.

command for windows => Shift + CTRL + F

link https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

[image]

Comment: thx for your reply , but it is not worked for me , still same even if i pressed the shortcut

Comment: Did you try with the right-click?
Clicked on the right-click and select the option "formate document with" and 
select the prettier as default.

Comment: Yes I trried it but it did not work .   But  it's still good plugin even it is not a solution for my problem .